# Energy-efficient way to reconstructing a signal from few samples

Tags: android, math, gps, signals, information-retrieval

I have a signal x[n] , n=1...N, N>10000. Assume that I know few samples at index i1, i2,.. ik , Can  i use these samples to get back x roughly ? For example, say  I have the GPS reading every one sec in an Android phone for an hour ( 3600 samples) , can I make a guess of the whole path (not fixed) i travelled from say just 100 sample ? This can save battery power and storage in case possible.
Another example could be an image Y[i,j]  where i have {(i1,j1), (i2,j2)..(ik,jk)} samples, and using these samples derive the full image. If the path or the image is described by any analytical function (say a circle or a predictable checkerboard) then it would not be difficult, but for a generic case, when the relations can not be analytically described, it could be interesting.

I understand if the signal x is completely random I would not be able be able make any clue  from few samples, but if it is not random ( say have some relationship/ correlations with the other samples), there should be a way to get at least some good idea about the whole signal, even though not completely accurate. Can anyone point any good algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is interpolation of data, I guess. I would say how to exactly do it say it depends on the nature of your signal. That's a very broad topic. Read e.g. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation